# Our SE allows multiple accounts then why our MOD deleting it?

Tags: discussion

See this META post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250565/can-i-create-a-new-and-clean-account-without-getting-it-merged-with-this-account?answertab=votes#tab-top), it clearly shows Multiple accounts are 100% allowed.

See I am not spamming our SE with bad questions.

Yesterday our MOD Napoelean Wilson deleted my 2 multiple accounts.

please don't delete it.

All my multiple accounts are registered with proper email address.

Comment: aside from this not being a proper question for the main site (and thus should be on the Meta site) if you used a proper email address you would have received an email stating why your account is removed, if you don't then how is a Mod supposed to explain their reasons to you without publicly exposing any wrong doing you are doing. if you are using the multiple accounts to upvote your own questions this is very much against the frist sentence of the answer you linked to *"As long as there won't be any illegal behaviour"*

Comment: You create multiple account to bypass the bans which is surely not allowed.

Comment: Why do you want to create multiple accounts on the first place? Can you justify your actions? You can post an answer to justify your acts. What's the problem maintaining a single account? What is the need of different account every time. If you are using multiple accounts to surpass suspensions, it is violating rules.

Comment: The question here is, **why don't you simply use a proper single account**? With an existing history of *actual sockpuppet voting* in the past we put a suspicious eye onto *any* kind of multiple accounts.

Answer (score 12):

You are right, the creation of multiple accounts isn't against the rules.

Assuming what [Ankit Sharma](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/our-se-allows-multiple-accounts-then-why-our-mod-deleting-it#comment10822_2846) said is true

> You create multiple account to bypass the bans which is surely not allowed.

then you are actually doing exactly what answer [you linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250566/250962) said not to do

> **As long as there won't be any illegal behaviour**, I believe you can. I see no problems with it.

But don't just take the word of a 0 scoring answer, also take [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35607/250962) as well.

> It is not a problem to have multiple accounts, **as long as they aren't voting for each other and doing other sockpuppet-y things.**
>
> Though it is generally discouraged, as what legitimate reason would you need for multiple accounts? Idle hands are the devil's playground, etc etc.

Also indicated on the Stack Overflow Meta [answer on question/answer bans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/1028804)

> ### Can I simply create a new account?
>
> Yes, but doing so violates the rules for operating multiple accounts - namely, [it allows you to do something you would otherwise be restricted from doing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange). **Penalties for violating this restriction can vary:**
>
> - **Your accounts may be deleted without warning.**
> - You and others on your network may find your questions are shown to fewer potential answerers or subjected to preemptive review when posted.
> - You and others on your network may be prevented from asking questions entirely.
> - If you opt to [delete your account](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) and then later return to the site, your ability to ask questions may be [limited to one question per week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/102937) until you have demonstrated an ability to ask useful questions.

As such, assuming Ankit Sharma is correct your other accounts were found to be circumventing a question ban on your original account. If you wish to remove the ban read the Stack Overflow Meta answer in how you can get out of it. While talking about spamming, please explain questions on the main site and abusing people will just make the situation worse and as indicated by the Meta, you can be blocked from asking questions at all.

Comment: Perfectly summarized,

Comment: And in addition to that, we are also a little less gracious with accounts that have previously been used for *actual sockpuppet voting*.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson and perhaps abusing.